# Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I am trying to write a sample app using Android architecture components and but even after trying for days I could not get it to work. It gives me the above exception.

Lifecycle owner:-

```
public class MainActivity extends LifecycleActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.tv_user);
        PostViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PostViewModel.class);
        viewModel.loadPosts();
        viewModel.getPost().observe(this, new Observer<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Post post) {
                if(post != null) {
                    textView.setText(post.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ViewModel:-

```
public class PostViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MediatorLiveData<Post> post;
    private PostRepository postRepo;

    PostViewModel() {
        post = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        postRepo = new PostRepository();
    }

    public LiveData<Post> loadPosts() {
        post.addSource(postRepo.getPost(),
                post -> this.post.setValue(post)
        );
        return post;
    }

    @NonNull
    public LiveData<Post> getPost() {
        return post;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Hilt and Compose Navigation,  check this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265726/13519865

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Make your constructor `public`.

Comment: However strangely Android studio gives a warning after making constructor public saying "Access can be package-private" .

Comment: @ParagKadam: Android Studio does not know that the lifecycle components need the constructor to be public. Android Studio only goes by what it can see through explicit code references.

Comment: Still getting the error in a fragment, both class and constructor are already public.

Comment: My constructor is public, but I received this error: Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.randa.android.model.search.SearchActivityViewModel
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:153)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:210)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
       at com.randa.android.

Comment: Funny thing is it works in debug mode but crashes when the app is compiled in release mode.

Comment: Both constructor and the class need to be public !

Comment: *And* the class must be static if it's a nested class in your Activity.

Answer (score 264):

if you are using `Hilt`, ensure your activity/fragment is having `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26963524)

Comment: well @AndriiOmelchenko, have you tried Hilt with injection in viewModel constructor? because I believe this is an honest mistake that most developers will make that will cause `Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel` crash during run-time.

Comment: I'm using Dagger Hilt, and that answer saved me a lot of time, thanks!

Comment: I always make the same mistake and find myself here. Thank you.

Comment: same here. I always always make the same mistake. wondering around then always find the answer here

Comment: This was an answer for me too. I wonder why some are so quick to give negative unhelpful views if they don;t have knowledge of a domain. On  another note, Fragments were working at some point without the `@AndroidEntryPoint`. The viewmodel jammed when i made it a little more complicated, with an injected argument in the constructor.

Comment: Even after putting @AndroidEntryPoin I'm getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel

Comment: In [feature modules](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module), the way that modules usually depend on each other is inverted. Therefore, Hilt cannot process annotations in feature modules. You must use [Dagger](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-basics) to perform dependency injection in your feature modules.

Comment: Latest `@HiltViewModel` on top of your viewModel

Comment: top!!!

if u need inject to viewmodel add @AndroidEntryPoint in this fragment!

Comment: @SamsadCV if this doesn't fix your problem, check your `ViewModel`-constructor params. If you have anything in there that isn't provided by a dagger/hilt-`@Module` in your project, then add a `@Provides`-method in that module. If you try to inject another `ViewModel` into your `ViewModel,` you have to create a `ViewModelFactory` with all needed constructor-params and method create to instantiate your `ViewModel` there. You cannot annotate that `ViewModel` with `@HiltViewModel` in that case, AFAIK.

Answer (score 30):

[DaggerHilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/) can also be the reason, If you are using it make sure your `activity/fragment` is having `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation on it.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using `Kotlin` make sure to replace any `annotationProcessor` in `build.gradle` with `kapt`.

Like:

`annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"`

Will become

`kapt  "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"`

and add

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` on top of the `buidl.gradle` file.

[Annotation Processing with Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-frameworks.html)

Comment: It fixed my problem. It may not be the right answer for java, but it is correct for "Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel in Kotlin"

Comment: @Eoghan I posted the answer for the exact same reason because it took me quite a while to understand this issue. But ppl are not gentle and keep downvoting lol even though I have clearly mentioned if you are using kotlin.

Comment: It saved me, i hate this android logger, i got an exception about something and the reason is actually something else

Comment: @Milos maybe you should use "log filters" in Android Studio.

Answer (score 23):

#### For people using Jetpack Compose, Navigation and Hilt

Make sure to use the `hiltNavGraphViewModel` instead of `viewModel`.

This is provided by `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose` dependency.

More details in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation).

Comment: Thank you! I used `viewModel` and got error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class my.app.MyViewModel`. But after using `hiltViewModel`, as stated in the documentation, everything worked!

Comment: I wasted quite some time on this error. Still valid in 2023, luckily docs show how to get ViewModel in NavHost. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Make sure your `ViewModel` has constructor with only one parameter i.e. `Application`.

example:

```
public YourViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, i created constructor of ViewModel Class get two arguments, I deleted one and good result.

Comment: yes it have only one parameter but its still crashing

Comment: Why can ViewModel only have one constr. parameter?

Answer (score 20):

Add `@HiltViewModel` on top of your viewModel .

Answer (score 15):

There are few reason to throw the exception . I have mention some of them..

1. Make sure your view Model class is public
2. Make sure your view model class constructor is public
3. Make sure you have added the dependency in your gradle file for
   lifecycle also if you use room and other libraries you have added ..
4. if you create object any other dependent class in your view model
   class constructor . Other class can throw error to create the
   instance of viewModel

Comment: Great for the 4th point!!! It really solves me after finding your step by step solution.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem following google's [roomdb CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#13). Solution was changing the following.

#### Edited

Add the following Build dependencies to Gradle file (as of 2/22/2020)

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0'
```

Imports within the fragment

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
```

Creating the viewModel. Add one of the following methods.

*Note*: I'v seen this done many ways. I believe the correct way is using `getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()`. But I have been using `requireActivity()`.

```
 new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(),getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

|

```
 new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(YourViewModel.class);
```

[ViewModelProvider Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider)

> Deprecated

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-rc01'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0-rc01'
```

Comment: The latest android lifecycle documentation says that the lifecycle-extensions dependency is now deprecated https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#
However, if I remove that dependency from the gradle file I am getting the cannot create an instance of class viewmodel error when I start my app.  I tried adding all of the other dependencies listed as current, even the optional ones, but it won't work without the lifecycle-extensions dependency.  For now, I have to keep the deprecated dependency.  I am still trying to find why it fails without this dependency.

Comment: Good info @Howard , I updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had the same issue following roomdb CodeLab, the only thing I had to add was     implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5'

Answer (score 6):

It was not completely obvious to me, but when getting this error I resolved it by creating a public constructor.  My constructor was derived from the Android Developer examples and contained the Repository as a parameter.  Creating an additional constructor that was empty with no params and having it public solved the issue.

i.e., in your case

`public PostViewModel() {}`

Comment: What if we need to pass parameters to ViewModel??

Comment: You can create an additional constructor for that one, but having a NoArgsConstructor is what is needed to solve this issue.

Comment: Where is the official documentation proving this?

Answer (score 6):

If you are use `Hilt`, your activity or fragment need `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation and also view model need `@HiltViewModel` annotation.

Answer (score 5):

Make the class and constructor public it solved my problem .

Answer (score 5):

Extend **AndroidViewModel** from your ViewModel class.

```
public class YourViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public YourViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);

        //Todo: ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you used viewmodel inside your activity check that your activity extends "DaggerAppCompatActivity" or not

For instance

```
public class UserComments extends AppCompatActivity
```

change this to

```
public class UserComments extends DaggerAppCompatActivity
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the reason was that I was trying to get a shared instance of the ViewModel in my fragment too soon - before the activity was created. What happens when the application is restoring its state after being killed.

**Preconditions**:

1. My ViewModel has a public constructor.
2. My ViewModel has multiple arguments. But this is absolutely fine as I use ViewModelFactory to construct the ViewModel.
3. My Fragment and Activity [shares the same instance of the ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing). In other words: Activity creates the ViewModel and the fragment receives the same instance later.

Code in activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //factory is constructed using Dagger
    val factory = App.get().components().appComponent.getMapViewModelFactory() 
    //activity creates the instance of MapViewModel
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)[MapViewModel::class.java]
}
```

Code in fragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    //fragment receives the instance of MapViewModel
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!)[MapViewModel::class.java]
    ...
}
```

When I open the app for the first time, everything works fine: activity creates an instance of ViewModel; I open Fragment, which gets the instance of ViewModel. But when the application is trying to restore its state after being killed, first it calls the body of onCreate of the Fragment and then the body of onCreate of the Activity. At that point, the fragment can't get the ViewModel as Activity had not created it yet.

**Solution 1**: Move the code when the fragment gets the ViewModel from onCreate to onViewCreated. This is fine as I observe all live data in onViewCreated as well.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = activity?.run { ViewModelProviders.of(this)[MapViewModel::class.java] } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

    viewModel.getSurveyDateLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<String> { dateTextView.text = it })
    ...
}
```

**Solution 2**:
Create the instance of ViewModel in *Activity.onCreate* before *super.onCreate* is called. In this case, you can get the ViewModel in your fragment's *onCreate*.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
    val factory = App.get().components().appComponent.getMapViewModelFactory()
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)[MapViewModel::class.java]
    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Timber.d("cc: onCreate: $this ")
}
```

**Solution 3**:

If you are injecting repository instance in your ViewModel, Check that you are not using `@Inject constructor(...): ViewModel()` to inject your repository, but rather `**@ViewModelInject constructor(...): ViewModel()**`

Answer (score 3):

1. Mostly, Solution is making Class and Constructor Public as the other answers
2. It may also be a runtime error, check the Logcat Error Logs if there are multiple causes listed.

Comment: Yes it is very important the the class is also `public`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Hilt then don't forget to add these four dependencies.

```
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01'
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

Note:- If any of these dependencies are missing you will get `Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel` error

Comment: I have all 4 still I am getting that error. I have 2 view model 1 on splash works well 1 on home gives this error -__0 . Although later is copied

Comment: This answer helped me. I was missing  **kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01"**. That alone prevented my ViewModel (with parameters in its constructor, no ViewModelFactory) from being created.

Comment: you're my hero. you save my time, thank you

Comment: @andika_kurniawan you can upvote your hero's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the same problem by doing this.

Note:- I am using Dagger hilt, Room database, MVVM, Data binding

Added the annotation.

```
class AlertViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val userRepository: AlertRepository) : ViewModel(){
    val getList:LiveData<List<Alert>> get() =
        userRepository.getList.flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
            .asLiveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext)

    fun insert(user:Alert){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userRepository.insert(user)
        }
    }
}
```

To

```
@HiltViewModel // Added this annotation
class AlertViewModel
@Inject
constructor(private val userRepository: AlertRepository) : ViewModel(){
    val getList:LiveData<List<Alert>> get() =
        userRepository.getList.flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
            .asLiveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext)

    fun insert(user:Alert){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            userRepository.insert(user)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this after migrating to AndroidX.

There's a bug in `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-beta01` where Proguard removes the constructor.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112230489

Fix by upgrading to 2.0.0, and remember to update your proguard rules if needed.

My error message looked like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class my.custom.viewmodel.CustomViewModel
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:202)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:135)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:103)
......
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.app.Application]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:200)
... 34 more


  androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 539, 1167 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: my.test:id/button_return_to_main_menu'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:82)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:79)
.....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.custom.domain.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class my.custom.viewmodel.CustomViewModel
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
```

Answer (score 2):

if your PostViewModel class is an inner class, make sure its public and static

Answer (score 2):

Please add below code. It worked for me

```
val binding = FragmentLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            requireActivity(),
            defaultViewModelProviderFactory
            ).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: and using -> @AndroidEntryPoint on fragment/activity

Comment: @umitx if you are using Hilt only than we have to do this in Activity

Answer (score 2):

If you face this issue in Kotlin Dagger Hilt even after @HiltViewModel and using @Inject, make sure you have updated all hilt dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to use a ListItemViewModelFactory to pass in a parameter to my view model.

Comment: Yes. We have to create `YourViewModelFactory(private val param: String) : ViewModelProvider.Factory` to have a parameter inside `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was gradle a dependencies problem.

If you are using Livedata,,

build.gradle(Module.app)

not

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
kapt 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1'
```

use these

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using  Hilt Dependency Injection, You probably have missed **@ViewModelInject**. Because, Hilt provide its own injection for viewmodel.

In my case, I used and @Inject due to this caught into the error.

Comment: If you face this issue in Kotlin Dagger Hilt even after adding annotations HiltViewModel and Inject, make sure you have updated all hilt dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I had a different scenario when creating a view model instance:

1. I was requesting for the instance in a fragment.
2. My ViewModel required a parameter to be passed on the constructor.
3. I was not using Dependency Injection.

Solution
In a scenario where your viewmodel requires a parameter to be passed you have to create a ViewModelFactory to define your instances

Solution In Practice

```
- ViewModel Sample

    class SharedViewModel(private val repository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {
    
     init {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                repository.refreshDataInDb()
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    

 - Creating ViewModel Factory

    
    class ViewModelFactory(
        private val repository: UserRepository
    ) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory(){
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    
         return SharedViewModel( repository as UserRepository) as T
          
        }
    }
    
    

 - Creating ViewModel Instannce in a Fragment

     private  lateinit var factory: ViewModelFactory
     private lateinit var searchViewModel: SharedViewModel
     private lateinit var repository: UserRepository
    

    repository = UserRepository()
    factory = ViewModelFactory(repository)
    searchViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), factory)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the IDE had added a "**abstract**" modifier to my ViewModel class.

Answer (score 0):

Make ViewModal class and constructure **public**

Answer (score 0):

If constructor of your viewmodel is public and accepts only application then make sure you can create your own model without `ViewModelProvider`. Error message might be much more clear:

```
val model = YouViewModel(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a proficient Android developer and I have used ViewModel 100s of times with no issue. Today I came across this issue. Spent hours and scrolled through various SO posts. Didn't get solved.

Then I saw that the package name in which I have the ViewModel contains `new`. Like this:

`com.myapp.myfeature.new.feature`

I changed `new` to `neww` for testing like this:
`com.myapp.myfeature.neww.feature`

and it worked! I hope someone find it useful.

Comment: Good that it worked for you, however this has not got anything to do with ViewModels, you just can't use a keyword in the package name.

Comment: Yes Parag but there was no warning and error didn’t point to it. It was only random event to discover that the issue was with Package name

Comment: You could have discovered this issue while working with anything else apart from ViewModels and just because you discovered this issue while implementing ViewModels doesn't make it a valid answer to the question asked above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2.33-beta and upper remove these dependencies;

```
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01"
```

Keep only these two dependency

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.33-beta"
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Jepack Compose with a `ViewModel` in your **component**.
The `@Preview` annotation may cause this error. That was the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well this will fix the issue for sure

**First of all make sure you have this dependency**

```
//Room DB
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

Then remove viewmodel constructor, then create init function as your constructor

```
 public void init(Application application){
        instance = new FirebaseDatabaseInstance();
        databaseRepository = new DatabaseRepository(application);
        allChatMembers = databaseRepository.getAllChatMembers();
    }
```

Then this will solve...

Answer (score 0):

Not for OP's case, but adding it here for newcomers.

If you inherit from *AndroidViewModel* and there is some heavy work in the main Thread (like accessing the database) it'll **wrongly** throw this error.

After I switched to inherit from *ViewModel*, it showed the correct error and I could move the heavy work to `Dispatchers.IO`. After moving UI blocking stuff to `Dispatchers.IO`, I re-tested using *AndroidViewModel* and everything works fine again.

Conclusion:
"UI blocking work on the main thread when inheriting from *AndroidViewModel* can throw this error".

Answer (score 0):

none of the above was my problem. I did added  `@HiltViewModel` and `@AndroidEntryPoint` and `@HiltAndroidApplication` like i had before and my code worked. the problem was that my project was multi-module and when i added the annotations it actually imported theme from other submodule but because the module didn't have those dependency in its own gradle.build it didn't compile, so i added these as same as other modules and it worked:

```
// Hilt
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.47")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44.2")
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm using this example [android-arcuitecture-component BasicSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample) to make a new project, facing a similar error log, found I did'n change de applicatio name

> AndroidManifest.xml

and that was my error, to fix put the aplicacion name to de BasicApp, this class is implement in the example.

```
...
<application
    android:name=".BasicApp"
    android:allowBackup="false"
```