# Cannot create viewmodel from composalbe function

Tags: dependency-injection, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

I have a view model.
I am using Hilt.
I can create this view model from activity, like this

```kotlin
val model: ProfileViewModel by viewModels()
```

However when I try to create this view model from a composable function

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel

@Composable
fun ProfileScreen(){
    val model: ProfileViewModel = viewModel()
    Button(onClick = {
        model.logout()
    }){
        Text(stringResource(R.string.log_out))
    }
}
```

I am getting error

```
2021-04-22 10:01:55.503 10482-10482/com.pulsariodev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pulsariodev, PID: 10482
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.pulsario.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:78)
        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:63)
        at com.pulsario.ui.profile.ProfileScreenKt.ProfileScreen(ProfileScreen.kt:23)
        at com.pulsario.ui.main.MainScreenKt$MainScreen$2$1$1$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:60)
        at com.pulsario.ui.main.MainScreenKt$MainScreen$2$1$1$1.invoke(MainScreen.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5$1$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:138)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5$1$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:137)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavHost.kt:150)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavHost.kt:1)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:137)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:136)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:193)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:132)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$6.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$6.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:97)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2117)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2375)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2517)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2488)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:546)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:733)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:102)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:443)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:415)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:965)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
2021-04-22 10:01:55.504 10482-10482/com.pulsariodev E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:722)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7386)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:980)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.pulsario.ui.profile.ProfileViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
            ... 52 more
```

Here is [the example](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt) from Android tutorial but this does not work for me.

Comment: You can't instantiate ViewModel object by constructor, to create the object you have two ways 1. by ViewModelProviders & 2. val model: ProfileViewModel by viewModels() extension provided in viewmodel-ktx lib

Comment: ViewModel bound to view lifecycle

Comment: in your case you can use this var model: ProfileViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of("activity-reference").get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)

Comment: But in this example they are doing this in the same way as I do https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt

Answer (score 6):

Because my composable function is created via navigation but not directly from Fragment or Activity I have to use the function

`hiltViewModel()`

Details in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation)

Comment: For some reason, in this case, the hilt cannot create a viewmodel if it contains your dependencies (provided via @Module). For example without dependencies or with SavedStateHandle dependency there is no creation error. The documentation is misleading "If ... is scoped to the navigation graph," - and if not, if you need exactly scoped to activity, then where does the error come from? Bug?

Comment: Now it's called `hiltViewModel()`

Comment: In case of navigation use
val exampleViewModel = hiltViewModel<ExampleViewModel>()

Comment: `hiltViewModel()` from navigation and `by viewModels` of activity provide different viewmodel instances right? Do you have to pass viewmodel as argument if you want to use the same viewmodel in activity and navigation?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

### Step 1

In the `Project build.gradle` file, define `lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-beta01"`

as in

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
        lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-beta01"
    }
    // rest is the same
```

**Important: It won't work with androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.3.1 and probably below**

### Step 2

In the `app build.gradle` file, make 3 changes: (1) change to `compileSdk 31`, (2) change to `targetSdk 31`, and (3) add to `dependencies` the following `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version"` and `implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"`

as in

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        //rest is the same
    }
}

//rest is the same

dependencies {
    //...
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

**Important: It won't work with compileSdk 30 and/or targetSdk 30**

### Step 3

Make sure to import `androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.*`

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.*
```

**Important: Must include the above import**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the below

```
class MyScreenManager(navController:NavigationController){

lateinit var viewModel:MyViewModel = HiltViewModelFactory(
            activity,
            navController.getBackStackEntry(MyScreen.route)
        ).create(MyViewModel::class.java)
}
```

The above class was not injected but navigated to from a composable function