# Cannot create an instance of class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

```
Cannot create an instance of class com.example.myapplication.CharactersViewModel
```

I am finishing pagination and I get such a stack of errors (first screen). On the second photo is my MainActivity. And on the third ViewModel. As I understand it, he cannot create an instance of the ViewModel class, but I don’t know why(

`1`[image]
`2`[image]
`3`[image]

Comment: Use ViewModelFactory!!

Comment: @VivekGupta where to use it?

Comment: Read Viewmodel with dependency https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than one reason. There is an issue already opened. Did you check here before? If not, the solution can be here.

[Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998051/cannot-create-an-instance-of-class-viewmodel)