# Hilt Multi-module Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, multi-module, android-multi-module

I'm trying out a new architecture with multi-module and DI though Hilt, I have the following modules:

- app: Contains MainActivity (which does nothing except holding fragment)
- featureHome: Contains HomeFragment and HomeViewModel

When I start the app I'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class HomeViewModel`

**App module**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity()
```

---

**FeatureHome**

```
class HomeFragment: Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()
    ...
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel {
    ....
}
```

I'm not sure what to do to resolve this. Should my HomeFragment also have `@AndroidEntryPoint` ?

Comment: [An activity or a fragment that is annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint can get the ViewModel instance as normal using ViewModelProvider or the by viewModels() KTX extensions:](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodels)

Comment: Yes it works when the `HomeFragment` and `HomeViewModel` are in the same module as the `MainActivity` but when I move them to my `featureHome` module this doesn't work anymore

Comment: HomeFragment must also have @AndroidEntryPoint as the other comment suggests. And make sure hilt is in both modules.

Comment: But why ? When both Fragment and Activity are in the same package you don't need to have @AndroidEntryPoint on the Fragment

Comment: You are injecting the ViewModel in your fragment with `by viewModels()`. This requires the annotation to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998051/cannot-create-an-instance-of-class-viewmodel)

Comment: @AtickFaisal that's what I'm saying when HomeFragment is in the same module as MainActivity it is not needed, why the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Fragment` has to be marked with the annotation `@AndroidEntryPoint` in order to tell Hilt to inject instances in your Fragment. ([documentation](https://dagger.dev/hilt/android-entry-point.html))